# Anyone else getting a webform error for a non-required date field?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I'm experiencing, in the current Webform version (7.x-4.16), an issue reported fixed last year ([issue #2612844](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2612844)). Anyone else experiencing it?

A date field with "Hide" checked for Day and Month (only interested in the year).  The hint says "A hidden day or month will be set to 1." Instead getting errors for Month missing and Day missing upon form submission.

Comment: Just noting, since it is potentially misundertandable (by me!), the 'fix' is to the pure Webform module, and not the webform_civicrm module

Comment: Good clarification petednz.  I am experiencing the issue with CiviCRM processing "on" for the webform.  The date field in the form is "wired" to set the end date of a CiviCRM relationship.  All I'm interested in is the year, but this issue is forcing me to ask for a full date.  Setting a default for the date doesn't help, once the year is changed the error manifests. I'm running version 7.x-4.19 of Webform CiviCRM Integration.

Comment: I expect this needs to be done as an 'improvement' to the webform_civicrm code - you might want to open an issue at https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm but it will probably require some effort/funding to get it added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I get this when I add a Relationship on a webform and set Day and Month to be hidden.

[image]

I expect this needs to be done as an 'improvement' to the webform_civicrm code - you might want to open an issue at drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm but it will probably require some effort/funding to get it added

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I created issue #2931633.  Up-voted your answer but I don't have enough reputation for it to show!

Comment: well there is +1 for you ;-)

Comment: think that gets you over 10 - how many do you need?

Comment: found your other questions so over 20 now - the sky is the limit

Comment: Many thanks!  I feel "official" now :-)

Comment: Does that mean you can Tick/Accept the answer? (not saying you should)

Comment: I can work around the problem now that I know it wasn't cockpit error.

Comment: Duh!  Took me this long to figure out that upvoting and accepting an answer are two separate steps.